# Xamarin Android, How do you go about rotating a Vector Drawable?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-vectordrawable

Edit: see my own answer, I have added more detail as I have managed to get an animation working through XMLs, I cannot see why the code I have isn't doing the same thing.

I'm trying in Xamarin Android (not Forms) to display a couple of Vector Drawables and have one of the rotate on the other.  The idea is a timer, a single hand going around a clock.  I'm after the hand to appear to do a couple of full rotations then stop at a random angle.  So it could stop at say 3 o'clock or 10 o'clock when it is done rotating.

I would have thought what I am trying to do would be done programmatically rather than via XMLs however I cannot find any good information to start me off on this. I'm not that familiar with base Android (I'm quite familiar with Xamarin Forms).

I can get both the face and the hand to display in an ImageView control.  This I have done with both a layer-list.xml and a LayerDrawable.  I have tried creating a RotateDrawable from the hand with a fromRotation and a toRotation set then applying that to LayerDrawbale. It does draw but not rotated.
The same  applies in the layer-list xml, both draw, the hand is without rotation.

I have tried searching here and google, I cannot find anything solid so far to get me started. just snippets of XMLs. I feel I'm missing something very fundamental.

Any help is massively apricated.

This is the xml for the layerlist

```
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
>
  <item    
      android:drawable="@drawable/Clock"/>
  <item>
    <rotate
      android:drawable="@drawable/Needle"
      android:pivotX="50%"
      android:pivotY="1%"
      android:fromDegrees="0"
      android:toDegrees="1080"
      />
  </item>
     
</layer-list>
```

The code for the setting the layer-list to a Imageview.

```
ImageView clockDisplay = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.ThreePlayers);
Drawable clock = VectorDrawableCompat.Create(Resources, Resource.Drawable.Clock, null);
clockDisplay.SetImageDrawable(clock);

/*
  I have also used the following to no avail.

  RotateDrawable clockRotate = new RotateDrawable();

  clockRotate.Drawable = needle;
  clockRotate.FromDegrees = 180;
  clockRotate.ToDegrees = 180;

  clockDisplay.SetImageDrawable(clockRotate);

*/
```

Cheers
Andy.

Comment: I think `layer-list` layer overlay it's a static layer,,so it's not going to rotate all the time, unless you animate the imageview.You could try to use two imageview  in a relative layout,one is clock,one is its hand,then  set the rotation animation for hand Imageview.

Comment: OK, that makes sense about the layer-list, 

How do you rotate a Vector Drawable anyhow, can you not just apply a rotation to it, then add the rotated Vector Drawable to a Layer? Or does the ImageView need to be rotated instead?

Comment: If you want to  rotate a drawable,you should set the rotate animation to the ImageView.

Comment: I have posted an answer to this, though as I first thought i had solved the problem which I haven't.   I can use layers to rotate only part of the vector drawable and I've managed to create an animation in pure XML, this does not solve my problem as I need to do it in code as the start and stop angles will be different each time.

I have  partial solution, thought I'm missing why it doesn't work as it appears that it should.

Comment: Thanks. I have the desired effect by using as you suggested two ImageViews in a RelativeLayour on stacked on the other. It works though seems like overkill to me. When simply animating part of the vector drawable seems a more elegant solution.

Is what I'm trying to do with the Vector Drawable possible?

Comment: Please check the answer I have edited as I still would like to know if it is possible to create an animation programmatically on a vector drawable without manipulating the container it is in.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:  I've changed this answer completely from what it was.

from the suggestions in the comments of the main post, I have got the rotation working by rotating the image view.

I have created a test program [here](https://github.com/BoardinCode/VectorAnimationTest)

that animates an ImageView with an AnimationSet and OhectAnimator, one using a Spring Animator and one that attempts to Animate the VectorDrawable directly in C#

The 1st two work as expected and is good enough for the project I am working on as all I need is rotation.

However is it not possible to Animate a VectorDrawable in C# without having animate the ImageView control?

If I creating a static animation in XMLs I could manipulate different layers of the VectorDrawable and Animate them Separately, surely this is possible to do in C#?

I'm starting to think it is not possible to do programmatically.|

Any advice?
Thanks.
Andy.